# Scheduled task doesn't run when WiFi connects(trigger)

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, batch, scheduled-tasks

I've created a scheduled task which should enable my hotspot when my wifi connects to a network, only, it doesn't do what it should do. 
I've tried both basic task and task with:
-'Event' as the Trigger and
-'Microsoft-Windows-NetworkProfile/Operational' as Log and
-'NetworkProfile' as Source and
-'10000' as EventID.
-'Run with highest privileges' is checked and the task is
-configured for Win8.1
- I've now only set a really simple batch script as action which echoes only one word to avoid any errors here
-Event logging was disabled once but it is enabled now i believe. Services.msc says it's auto-started, and currently running.

It just doesn't do anything when i connect my wifi, but when i manually demand the task to run, it runs fine. I really don't know what i did wrong, is it the ID number? Or still this event logging?
i don't know.. I have the Windows 8.1 system.
any help would be greatly appreciated!
let me know if more info is needed to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i started eventvwr.exe and searched for the used source and event to check the values.
I attached a task to ID 10000 which seriously exactly does the same thing i did when i manually created a task with these properties.
Now it works somehow. In addition i disabled UAC. Don't know if that matters.
Another option is to replace the .bat file with a shortcut to the batfile, but of course this is less decently programmed.